# Does test network account reset when I restart the node?

Tags: go-ethereum

When I start a test network (using `geth --ropsten --syncmode ~~etc` command) and enter console (using `geth attach <ipc_address>` command) to see the balance of my accounts, it's always empty.  Even though I faucet them before. So I need to faucet the accounts again.

Does the balance of accounts always reset after I stop the network?

Comment: The balance should not reset. Did the node finish syncing? Until it is complete the balances will show zero ethers.